# Timing out urlretrieve

Tags: python

How do I do a timeout with urllib.urlretrieve?

```
urllib.urlretrieve('http://%s/?action=snapshot' % (self.internal_streamer_address), "static/images/printer_jobs/printer_job_%s.jpg" % (printer_job.id))
```

Comment: There is an automatic timeout on synchronous connections like this (provided by your OS). Are you looking for a shorter timeout, or a longer one?

Comment: shorter timeout like 2 seconds

Comment: did you figure out a way to change the timeout?